# Cross Domain Tracking - see original source in Real-Time Reports

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, google-tag-manager

I have set up Cross Domain Tracking for two different domains with two different GTM containers. I added both domains, a.com and b.com in the Auto Link Domains in both Universal Analytics tags, set Allow Linker for both to true and set Cookie Domain to auto. However, when I'm surfing from Facebook to website a.com and click through to b.com I see a.com / referral as a traffic source in the real-time reports in Google Analytics. This should be Facebook in this case right? Does someone have a method to debug this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same issue and can't find a way to solve it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use Referral Exclusion List in Property Tracking info. This will exclude traffic from a.com from referrals.

Comment: I already tried that, but after I use that, should I then see Facebook as the source in my real-time reports? That way I can check if it's working. At the moment I'm getting Direct / (none) as the source/medium for the example described above. That doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: I couldn`t check this now on my GA, sorry. But if u can, try it.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you are not a Google Analytics Premium member?

The second thought is maybe you are using ***two Google Analytics properties*** (one for each domain) and not using ***one property*** for both domains?

To be able to utilize the cross domain function you must have ***one Google Analytics property*** associated to all domains. You might have the results of funny "referral sources" because you are using ***two different properties (UA-1111111-1 and UA-2222222-2.***

[Read more about multiple cross domains](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032400?hl=en)

[Or for specific cross domain info](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en) (notice the part about "UA PROPERTIES)

Let me know if that is the issue, and what your next strategy might be.